# add logo in page with vitepress

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, vitepress

i´m trying to create page with vitepress. All my page i can show it ok, but i can´t show my favicon and my logo image.

I´m traying to create this params in `config.js` with:

```
themeConfig: {
      logo: './../img/logo_liquid_cuadrado.png',
      head: [
        ['link', { rel: "icon", type: "image/png", sizes: "32x32", href: "/assets/img/logo-cnmc-cuadro.png"}],
      ],
```

I´m doing to compile: `npm run docs:dev` and i can show all my page.

i updated my proyect from vuepress to vitepress in vuepress my image i can show it perfectly...

I have same problem with favicon... i can´t show it.

I´m working with vuejs 3, vitepress and laravel 10.

i tryed to change `'./img', '/img/', '../img/'` and i´m getting same problem. How i´m working with laravel, i need access to `public folder` and in this folder i have img with this image

i appreciated all help

Comment: does this help you? [link](https://github.com/vuejs/vitepress/issues/560), also try to open that on browser like: `http://yoursite.com/assets/img/logo-cnmc-cuadro.png`if it opens, the path is correct

Comment: @francisco thanks for your response. i read this doc but i could show my page. now i cant show it. i cahnge my favicon and logo to other location

Comment: Did you opened the path on browser without problem? use that href. you can set with `public file path` like `logo: '/hero.png',`, or `using url` like `logo: 'https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png'`.